# How to build angular 8 project as .war file

Tags: javascript, java, angular, maven, user-interface

I would like to know how to build the angular app to .war file so that i can deploy to WAS server using maven

Answer (score 0):

A war file structure will be as below

```
Root/ - Web resources.
    WEB-INF/ - directory for application support
       lib/ - supporting jar files
       web.xml - configuration file for the application
```

Place your html, js and css files in the root of the war file which will be served as web resources. you can ignore the WEB-INF/lib folder since angular don't need any java library.

Comment: is it possible to build war file from my code editor itself is there any command!!

Comment: you should use build tools like maven or gradle to build the war file which will be easy and realilable.

Comment: can you please help me with the links for maven build as war file

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-pack-angular-8-applications-on-regular-war might help

Answer (score 0):

You can try using grunt for angular-grunt-build.
Please refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-grunt-build

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with maven by creating a build plugin for executing the build of angular application.
Build plugins will be executed during the build and they should be configured in the  element from the POM.

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>npm</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>install</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>npm</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>run</argument>
                                <argument>build</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

It is important for you to have already installed the node js, npm before. If not the maven build will fail because it will not find the environment need to run a build of angular app.

After that we modify the maven-war-plugin. The directory that we specify below will be location angular app  in war  generated by maven build.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <webResources>

                        <resource>
                            <targetPath>resources</targetPath>
                            <filtering>false</filtering>
                            <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
                            <directory>../path when you want to put angular app /dist/</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.*</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```